# Are there deep neural networks that have inputs connected with deeper hidden layers?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, architecture, hidden-layers

Are there any architectures of deep neural networks that connect input neurons not only with the first hidden layer but also with deeper ones (red lines on the picture)?

[image]

If so could you give some names or links to research papers?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17190/2444. Well, at least, I answer your question there too.

Comment: @nbro Well, I don't think this question is a duplicate, but yes there is an answer to my question in the linked one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of connections are called skip or residual connections. There are numerous works which employs this type of mechanism, for example: [ResNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf), [SkipRNN](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HkwVAXyCW). In addition [here](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C16-1020.pdf) you can find a paper that empirically explores the skip connections for sequential tagging, or this [one](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11265-020-01518-1) for speech enhancement.